# What is the purpose of script evaluation environment settings object set

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

If you work with JavaScript, you probably know about event loop along with macro and micro tasks. So whatwg spec defines a structure of any **task** that consists from:

- steps
- source
- document
- script evaluation environment settings object set

If the first three steps are clear the last one is unclear. It is mostly used in the "prepare to run script" for gathering "environment settings objects" and also it is used as part of event loop for reporting long tasks using gathered "environment settings objects".

**My question is:** What is this case when the task has in the "script evaluation environment settings object set" more than one "environment settings object"? An example wouldn't be excess.

---

**My supposition:** There is one place in whatwg spec that says the following:

> These algorithms are not invoked by one script directly calling another, but they can be invoked reentrantly in an indirect manner, e.g. if a script dispatches an event which has event listeners registered.

Hence the example will be following:

```js
/// example based on the chromium flag --process-per-site
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("task has been started");

    const auxiliary = window.open("about:blank"); /// or address from same origin
    
    auxiliary.document.body.onclick = () => {
        auxiliary.document.writeln(`<script>const observer = new PerformanceObserver((list) => {
            for (const entry of list.getEntries()) {
                console.log(entry);
            }
        });
        observer.observe({entryTypes: ['longtask']});</script>`);
        auxiliary.document.writeln("Here we go");
            
        auxiliary.document.body.onclick = "";
    };
    auxiliary.document.body.click();

    const start = performance.now();
    while(performance.now() < start + 3000);
    
    console.log("heavy computation in the entry script is over");
})
```

What do we see? We see that this code produces one task, also it creates auxiliary browsing context for that is making an observer. Finally this observer is firing in the auxiliary context during the long task.

So I can conclude that this code demonstrating how the task can have more than one "environment settings object" in set of the task structure.

Comment: The environment settings object is described in [8.1.3.2](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#environment-settings-objects).  Yes, a script in one environment can trigger a script that runs in a different environment (in your example a new browser window).   Can you clarify what question you have about that?

Comment: @DanielBeck In some parts of the specification, the operation "prepare to run script" is specified, which just works with the "script evaluation environment settings object set". So lately I've decided to understand promises thoroughly, and so I started learning whatwg. And in the HostEnqueuePromiseJob operation, I see "prepare to run script" and I don't understand why this is being done. What is the meaning of "prepare to run script" in promise?

Comment: That's explained in 8.1.5.3.3.   If you're trying to understand how to use Promises, you've gotten pretty deep in the wrong weeds: this stuff is relevant primarily to people building a javascript runtime engine, less so to those using them.

Comment: This is about [Execution Contexts](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-execution-contexts) not tied specifically to promises, that could be any async task like `setTimeout`. Since per specs "there is at most one execution context per agent", then before running a promise which was created in the current `window` context there could be another task with another context, let's say of an `iframe`, thus the context should be changed to that of the promise, and that is the "prepare to run script".