# Behavior of Global Execution Context wrt setTimeout

Tags: javascript, executioncontext

Let's say I have the following piece of code

```
function perpetuity() {
  console.log("Being called");
  setTimeout(perpetuity, 1500);
}

perpetuity();
```

I would like to know if the global execution context is present in the call stack so that this code can be executed.
OR
If the global execution context is created and deleted along with the callback function's execution context every 1500ms.

Chat gpt says GEC never stops but I cannot find the GEC in my browser's call stack when executing this.

Comment: Of course a global context remains -- after all, while that is running, you can interact with e.g. `window` in your browser's console..?

Comment: My question is whether it remains in the callstack or does it get added and deleted every 1500ms. Also if it remains why can't I see it in the browser's callstack

Comment: Whether _what_ remains? Also, what difference would it make, i.e. why do you need to know this? (Also, this sounds esoteric enough that different browsers could do different things.)

Comment: GEC remains or not. I am learning JS and that's why I need to know this

Comment: Well, where do you think `console.log` and `setTimeout` come from? What if you run that code, then type `setTimeout = null;` in your console? What do you think happens?

Comment: console.log and setTimeout are web apis present in the browser and they are present in the browser. To make my question clear: when there's nothing in the call stack for JS to execute will the GEC get destroyed for that brief period of time and recreated or not. Of course if I write something else call stack is not empty and GEC is there.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73416840/1048572

Comment: What do you _mean_ with "console.log and setTimeout are web apis present in the browser and they are present in the browser"? You can make them un-present, as illustrated above. Anyway, why would a browser spend any time and effort destroying and recreating things if it doesn't need to?

Answer (score 1):

There is no "global execution context". (I assume you're not confusing this with the [global environment record](https://262.ecma-international.org/13.0/#sec-global-environment-records)?)

There is however a [realm execution context](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#realm-execution-context) for all js code running in a browser. It is not actually useful for anything and more of a technicality (to allow tracking the realm that caused the execution), but it is [pushed to the execution context stack](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#prepare-to-run-script) before running any JS code and [popped afterwards](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#clean-up-after-running-script). It is created in [*InitializeHostDefinedRealm*](https://262.ecma-international.org/13.0/#sec-initializehostdefinedrealm) together with the intrinsics, the global object and the global environment of the realm, to [create the realm](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#creating-a-new-javascript-realm).